# Continuity and Bounded by a Geometric Series

Tags: analysis, continuity

I am reading a paper that defines a polynomial $Q(x)$ as follows. Let $x\in[0,1)$ and let $a_0 = 1-x$ and $a_j=x^{2^{j-1}}-x^{2^j}$. Then they define

$$Q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(x)^2$$

They claim that $Q(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ because it is 'bounded by a geometric series.' I am not sure what steps they're skipping or if I am just forgetting undergrad analysis but I am pretty sure bounded doesn't imply continuous. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, they skipped a small step. Here is a complete argument:

Consider $Q$ on some interval $[0,b]$, where $b\in(0,1)$. Define the partial sums
$$Q_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j(x)^2$$
so that $Q=\lim_{n\to\infty}Q_n$ in the pointwise sense. Furthermore we have the bound
$$0\leq a_j\leq x^{2^{j-1}}\leq x^{j}\leq b^j.$$
$b^{2j}$ is a convergent series so $Q_n\to Q$ uniformly on $[0,b]$ by the Weierstrass M test. Each $Q_n$ is continuous so $Q$ is continuous on $[0,b]$ by the uniform limit theorem.

The final step is to observe that $Q$ is continuous on every such $[0,b]$ so it is continuous on $[0,1)$.